# Занесение ид и текста в бд

Tags: php, mysql

не могу понять как сделать такую штуку, уже сижу долго. Есть таблица events в которую нужно занести ид категории и текст этой категории. Я уже и через сессию пробовал, но текст категории не соответствовал ид.

Вот форма

```
<form action="editprofile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <label>Название</label><br>
                                <input type="text" name="name_event" required><br>
                        <label>Категория</label><br>
                        <select name="cat_event">
                        <?php $query = "SELECT `id`,`category` FROM `category_events`"; 
                        $categories =  mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                        ?>  
                        <option></option>
                        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($categories)){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['category'] ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </select></br>
                        <label>Місто проведения</label><br>
                        <select name="location_event">
                        <?php $query = "SELECT `id`,`title` FROM `location`"; 
                        $locations =  mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                        ?>  
                        <option></option> 
                        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($locations)){ ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></option>
                        <?php } ?>
                      </select></br>
                                <label>Изображение</label><br>
                                <input required type="file" type="file" name="img_event" multiple accept="image/*,image/jpeg"><br>
                                <label>Начало</label> - 
                                <input required type="date" name="start_event">
                                <label>Конец</label> - 
                                <input required type="date" name="end_event"><br>
                                <label>Корот. описание</label><br>
                                <textarea required name="preview_event" cols="80" rows="5"></textarea><br>
                                <label>Полное описание</label><br>
                                <textarea required name="full_event" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea><br>
                                <input type="submit" name="btn_new_event">
                                </form>
```

Вот обработчик

```
    <?php 
// add event
    if(isset($_POST['btn_new_event'])){
    $id_user = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $title = $_POST['name_event'];
    $category = ""; в эту переменную нужно занести название равное $id_cat(ниже)
    $id_cat = $_POST['cat_event'];
    $location = "";а в эту переменную нужно занести название равное $id_loc(ниже)
    $id_loc = $_POST['location_event'];
    $post_event = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
    // image
    $uploaddir= '../img/eventimg/'; 
    $fot = $_FILES['img_event']['name'];
    $fot_dir = $uploaddir.$fot;

    $start_date_event = $_POST['start_event'];
    $end_date_event = $_POST['end_event'];
    $add_date_event = date("Y-m-d");
    $preview_event = $_POST['preview_event'];
    $full_event = $_POST['full_event'];

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['img_event']['tmp_name'], $fot_dir)) {
    $result_query_ev = "INSERT INTO `events` (`title`, `pre_event`, `image`, `id_cat_event`, `post_event`, `start_event`, `end_event`, `add_event`, `big_event`, `id_loc_event`, `text_category`, `text_location`, `id_user`) VALUES ('$title','$preview_event', '$fot_dir','$id_cat', '$post_event', '$start_date_event', '$end_date_event', '$add_date_event', '$full_event', '$id_loc', '$category', '$location', '$id_user')";
    $result_add = mysqli_query($conn,$result_query_ev) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if($result_add) {
        echo "<script>alert('Опубликовано!');location='user?id=".$id_user."'</script>"; 
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Не опубликовано!');location='user?id=".$id_user."'</script>";
    }
}}  
?>
```

Comment: Сразу возник вопросик. Для чего Вам нужно сохранять текст категории? если достаточно только id данной категории?

Comment: Я вывожу название категории к посту.

Comment: Для этого Вам достаточно id и тянуть категорию через JOIN?.

Comment: Чет не подумал, спасибо. А все таки как я хочу , возможно такое сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну можно попробовать так
заменить

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($categories)){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['category'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

на

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($categories)){ ?>
    <option value="<?= $row['id'] . '_' . $row['category'] ?>"><?= $row['category'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

и в скрипте

```
$category_data = explode('_', $_POST['cat_event']);
$id_cat = category_data[0];
$name_cat = category_data[1];
```

Comment: Но это как один из вариантов)))

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сделал как вы говорили выше.